# Dictionary and for-loop

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm trying to figure out how to create a for loop in a dictionary where I'm suposed to print both age and names above 25.

I've only managed to print the ages above 25 in the loop but only in a list and I'm not sure how to do it in a dictionary.

So basically I want to know how to print out both the names and ages above 25.

I'm fairly new to python and programming in general and would appreciate some advice and help :)

Comment: What dictionary do you have? Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: taking a complete stab in the dark: `for name, age in my_dict.items(): if age>25: print(name,age)`  although seeing the code you are working with would really help understand what you are having trouble with.

Comment: name = {"Peter" : 20, "John" : 32, "Ana" : 25, "Mike" : 22, "Connor" : 26, "Chelsea" : 29, "George" : 18, "Helen" : 33}
for x in name:
    if x >= 25:
        print name
Thanks for the reply.
This is what I've got so far, but it is obviously not working.

Comment: what do you expect `x` to represent in your code? try running `help(name.items)` and try using the code I posted in above comment replacing `my_dict` with `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
names = {"Peter" : 20, "John" : 32, "Ana" : 25, "Mike" : 22, "Connor" : 26, "Chelsea" : 29, "George" : 18, "Helen" : 33}
for name, age in names.iteritems():
    if age > 25:
        print(name+", "+age)
```

Should do the job. `iteritems` lets you unwrap all keys and values as a tuple in a loop, it's super useful for these kind of things.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using iteritems()...

```
final_list = [(name, age) for name, age in names.iteritems() if age > 25]
```

Now you can print the list